# argparse multiple optional arguments with nargs='?'

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use argparse to process several optional arguments. Each of the arguments will have a single optional argument as well. For example I have a script called runner.py. I want to call runner.py --functionals --capacity --performance and I want it to use the const values I have set. This part is working. I also want to be able to specify arguments such as --functionals test1 --performance test2 and --capacity test3. Instead of const, now I except the arguments to have the given values. for ex. functionals should be test1, performance test2 etc. What results in the latter case is I get: -c: error: argument --performance: not allowed with argument --functionals

Code for the parser looks like:

```
def get_parser():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
required_arguments = parser.add_argument_group(title = "required arguments")
test_arguments = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

test_arguments.add_argument( 
    '--capacity',
    nargs='?',
)
test_arguments.add_argument( 
    '--functionals',
    nargs='?',                      
)
test_arguments.add_argument( 
    '--performance',
    nargs='?',
)
return parser
```

Comment: set the const value as the default value parameter in the add_argument function.

Answer (score -1):

My mistake was that I was using a [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argument-groups). I should have been using an regular argument group.